# Same derivative of two functions in a point

Tags: real-analysis

First of all: sorry for the vague title. I am thinking about the following:
Let $f,g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be $C^1$ functions and there exists a point $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0)=g'(x_0)$. Is this enough to say that there exists an $\varepsilon >0$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon$? Or do I need stronger conditions?

Comment: No, consider $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x^3$ at the point $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the taylor expansions of $f$ and $g$ around $x_0$ in an $\epsilon$ neighbourhood. The first two terms are the same but unless the other terms are same as well, they are not equal.

Comment: To be rigorous, this answer needs the assumption of analyticity on both $f$ and $g$. There are counterexamples if one of them is allowed to be non-analytic. But this is a good answer nonetheless, it is a nice point of view.

Comment: The counterexample I was referring to is the function 
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}, & x\ne 0\\ 0, & x=0,\end{cases}$$ which is such that $0=f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=\ldots$, but it is not true that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I agree! I did not notice that the functions are only $C^1$.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample has been given, but the reverse is true: If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in(x_{0}-\epsilon,x_{0}+\epsilon)$, then
\begin{align*}
f'(x_{0})&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0,~|h|<\epsilon}\dfrac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0,~|h|<\epsilon}\dfrac{g(x_{0}+h)-g(x_{0})}{h}\\
&=g'(x_{0}).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Consider $h(x) = f(x) - g(x).$
The conditions of this question are that $h(x_0) = h'(x_0) = 0.$
Are those conditions sufficient to ensure that $h(x) = 0$ everywhere in a neighborhood around $x_0$?

Answer (score 0):

A counter example you can look at is $g(x)=x,\ f(x)= 2^{-1}x^2$, $x_0=\ ?$.